# How to understand one class svm(1-svm)?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am studying 1-SVM, reading papers there was notation "the origin".
However, I couldn't find any explanation for the definition.
The only thing I got is the origin is just (0,0). 
or...

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/One-class-SVM-the-origin-means-the-only-original-member-of-second-class_fig3_220537160
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/One-class-SVM-The-origin-0-0-is-the-single-instance-with-label-1_fig1_307538070

I can understand SVDD but 1-SVM it hard for me..
Would you explain the origin for me?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly what you found: the zero-reference point for the data, which is the starting point for each of the vectors of the SVM.

If the location bothers you for some reason, you're welcome to translate the data as you wish.  For instance, you could shift all the points such that the origin in at the centroid, such that the vectors will tend to radiate outward in all directions.

We're doing many strange and wonderful things with machine learning ... but we haven't yet redefined zero.  :-)
It's still the **origin** you learned in your introduction to the Cartesian plane.

Comment: The reason why I cannot understand was what if data is under 0 or near 0. I am not sure but, I roughly understood it. Thank you so much!

Comment: What don't you understand about small numbers and negative numbers?